# Getting a raw string back for use in Javascript in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: javascript, scala, escaping, playframework-2.0

I am currently trying to dynamically generate Javascript using a Scala object in my Play application, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">@JavascriptGenerator.generateChangingTextScript()</script>
```

This Javascript contains characters that Play wants to escape automatically, such as a quote ("). It automatically turns it into:

```
&quot;String goes here&quot;
```

rather than the desired:

```
"String goes here"
```

The Javascript being returned does not like this, and as such does not work. How do I tell Play to not do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Play 2 equivalent to Play 1’s `${"<".raw}` is `@Html("<")`.

Answer (score 0):

In play 1.2.4, there's the methode .raw() that returns the raw content of a property in a template. Did you try @JavascriptGenerator.generateChangingTextScript().raw();
That might work.

Comment: I tried that before asking this question; sorry for not indicating as such. At any rate, it broke the program. I guess that's deprecated, or I need a particular import to use it.